# Can NetBeans autoreplace text as I type?

Tags: netbeans-8

I have Gedit set up with snippets, so that when I type <kbd>X</kbd><kbd>X</kbd><kbd>X</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd> it automatically replaces `xxx` with `exit(__FILE__ . ': ' . __LINE__);`. Is there any way to achive the same effect in NetBeans? Searching for autocorrect or ways of replacing text finds me other, unrelated features.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it has , but you should do your owns, there is someones that are already built inside netbeans, go to `Tools - Options - Code Templates`

There you can edit your owns or just use the default ones, this is the window

[image]

if i write `Pfm` and press tab it auto completes

[image]

[image]

Side note:

if you want to autoComplete while you are writing just go to the left tab `Code Completion`

[image]